# Google Charts API (QR Code) returns HTTP error 502

Tags: qr-code

Do you have also the problem, that your QR Codes not loading anymore? This is because Google Charts is not longer active. Google disabled this service in the last few days! So if you're struggling, this is the reason:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-chart-api/rZtHTyYgyXI

You need to use the new Google Charts tools for this:

https://developers.google.com/chart/

I'll figure out, how to replace the old implementation for generating QR Codes and let you know, how you can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also found a good solution if you just want to use an URL like with Google before:

http://goqr.me/api/

The problem is, that the new Google API don't has QR Codes implemented anymore - sadly.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem some months ago, so I just did my own QR Code Generator, I have used Laravel Framework (PHP) to solve this:

First I have used this library:

[simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode](https://www.simplesoftware.io/simple-qrcode/)

This is for PHP of course

Something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode;

class QrCodeController extends BaseController
{
    /**
    * @param $uuid
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function generate($parameter) {
        $fileName = $parameter.'.png';
        $file = storage_path()."/".$this->app_directory."/".$fileName;
        QrCode::format('png')->size(1000)->generate($parameter, $file);

        return Response::download($file, $fileName)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }
}
```

Then I just add to routes file:

```
Route::get('qr/{parameter}', 'QrCodeController@generate');
```

This is just an idea about the way I solve this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your way! Also a good and independently solution.

Comment: Thanks, this saved my bacon during a recent outage of the endpoint. Now we are the masters of our own QR Code Fate!